# C++ - char to char16_t*

Tags: c++, winapi, format

Im trying to convert formated char to char16_t*

Im currently doing this but it results random charachters:

```
char msg[12];
sprintf_s(msg, 12, "-%dHP", txt->damage);
Interfaces::CenterPrint()->Print((char16_t*)msg);
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is char16_t ? and could it be that sizeof(char) is 1, and sizeof(char16_t) is 2 ?

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Im using visual studio 2017 on windows 10

Comment: `wchar_t msg[12]; swprintf_s(msg, 12, L"-%dHP", txt->damage);` should do the job.

Comment: It only prints the  "-"

Comment: You probably forgot the `L` before `"-%dHP"`: `L"-%dHP"`

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Please post answers as _answers_. Then we can all vote on them, the OP can accept them etc. I believe I previously informed you of this yesterday. Not sure why you're so insistent on using the comment section for answering questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's just because I'm not sure if this is really the problem.

Comment: Answering a question is often rewarded with lots of down votes for not being perfect.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Then perhaps it would be better to leave it to someone more sure? :) Uncertainty isn't really a good reason to answer in the wrong place (if anything, that's _double bad_ because your suggestion cannot be peer reviewed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot type-cast a `char[]` to `char16_t*` like you are doing. `char` is 1 byte in size, but `char16_t` is 2 bytes in size.  The `char` data won't be interpreted correctly when read as `char16_t` data.

On Windows, `wchar_t` is also 2 bytes in size. You can format your data into a `wchar_t[]` buffer instead, and then type-cast it to `char16_t`:

```
wchar_t msg[14];
swprintf_s(msg, 14, L"-%dHP", txt->damage);
Interfaces::CenterPrint()->Print(reinterpret_cast<char16_t*>(msg));
```

Alternatively:

```
char16_t msg[14];
swprintf_s(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(msg), 14, L"-%dHP", txt->damage);
Interfaces::CenterPrint()->Print(msg);
```

However, this is highly platform-specific. On many platforms, `wchar_t` is 4 bytes in size instead.

Since your message text contains only ASCII characters, a safer and portable solution would be to create a separate `char_t[]` buffer that contains a copy of each `char`:

```
char msg[14];
sprintf_s(msg, 14, "-%dHP", txt->damage);

char16_t msg2[14];
std::copy(msg, msg+14, msg2);
// or:
// std::transform(msg, msg+14, msg2, [](char c){ return (char16_t)c; });

Interfaces::CenterPrint()->Print(msg2);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) to convert the `char[]` data into a `std::u16string`:

```
char msg[14];
int len = sprintf_s(msg, 14, "-%dHP", txt->damage);

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>, char16_t> conv16;
std::u16string strMsg = conv16.from_bytes(msg, msg+len);

Interfaces::CenterPrint()->Print(strMsg.c_str());
```

Alternatively, you can use [`std::basic_ostringstream<char16_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to create a `std::u16string` directly and not use `char[]` at all:

```
std::basic_ostringstream<char16_t> msg;
msg << u"-" << txt->damage << u"HP";

std::u16string strMsg = msg.str();

Interfaces::CenterPrint()->Print(strMsg.c_str());
```